# Multi-variable chain rule example

Tags: multivariable-calculus, chain-rule

Let $p(x,y,z) = q(q(x^2, xy), q(xyz, sin(x^2y^2z^3)))$ where $q$ is a function of 2-variables. Find all partial derivatives.

What I know/tried: Chain rule needs to be applied but the main issue is how the function is written. I have tried to take the derivative w.r.t $x$ but it is a landscape page wide.

Bonus Question: Does $\frac{\partial p}{\partial z}$ exist?

Comment: I agree that the function is written rather weirdly. How about make it that $s=q(x^2,xy)$ and $t=q(xyz,\sin (x^2y^2z^3))$, so that $p(x,y,z) = q(s,t)$. This notation might help.

Comment: @Bob1123 I didn't think about substitution like this! Great idea. I think I am going to take it a step further: Let $a = x^2, \; b=xy$ etc and try that.

Comment: at that point however, the chain rule can get very long. There's a balance between how the notation creates an ease of use and how cumbersome it becomes.

Answer (score 0):

Using the comments I think I have figured it out:
Let $a = q(x^2, xy)$ and $b = q(xyz, sin(x^2y^2z^3))$.

Quickly take the partials w.r.t $x$ now...

$\frac{\partial a}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial q}{\partial x^2}(2x) + \frac{\partial q}{\partial xy}(y)$

and

$\frac{\partial b}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial q}{\partial (xyz)}(yz) + \frac{\partial q}{\partial (sin(x^2y^2z^3))}(cos(x^2y^2z^3)(2xy^2z^3))$

So then rewrite and apply chain rule...

$p(x,y,z) = q(a, b)$

$\frac{\partial p}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial q}{\partial a}\frac{\partial a}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial q}{\partial b}\frac{\partial b}{\partial x}$

After this, we substitute the work we did and since $q$ is arbitrary, we leave the ones with $q$.

$\frac{\partial p}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial q}{\partial a}[\frac{\partial q}{\partial x^2}(2x) + \frac{\partial q}{\partial xy}(y)]+ \frac{\partial q}{\partial b}[\frac{\partial q}{\partial (xyz)}(yz) + \frac{\partial q}{\partial (sin(x^2y^2z^3))}(cos(x^2y^2z^3)(2xy^2z^3))]$

Rinse and repeat for y and z.

Bonus question: Yes this derivative does exist.